# Error: Dart exception from converted Future. Use the properties 'error' to fetch the boxed error and 'stack' to recover the stack trace

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I found this error when running a firebase transaction in my flutter app:

```
 Error: Dart exception from converted Future. Use the properties 'error' to fetch the boxed error and 'stack' to recover the stack trace
```

A typical transaction as below:

```
 await _firestore.runTransaction<bool>(
    (transaction) async {
       ...   // things went here.
    }
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: add a try-catch block inside the async function.

Journey: After some tinkering, I realised that the error was because the async function in the runTransaction() raised an error from it without being properly handled by using try-catch block.

After I added a try-catch block, the problem was solved.

```
await _firestore.runTransaction<bool>(
    (transaction) async {
       try {
           ...   // things went here.
       } catch (e) {
           ...   // error-handling
       }
    }
 )
```